# How to move cars from one shard to another?

Tags: need-for-speed-world

In one shard, I have lots of customized high-end cars. I want to move some of them to another shard to be on top. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to NFSDrew (ex-community manager of NFSW):

> There is currently no way to transfer drivers or car from one shard to another.

[(Source)](http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/9399694.page#27871705)